# Implementing a templated interface

Tags: c#, interface, refactoring

I'm trying to write this more generically:

```
public static CormantRadDock RecreateDock(RadDockSetting settings)
{
    CormantRadDock dock = new CormantRadDock();
    settings.SetSettings(dock);
    Logger.DebugFormat("Recreated dock {0}", dock.ID);
    return dock;
}
```

I have this:

```
public static T Recreate<T>() where T : new()
{
    T _control = new T();
    //settings.SetSettings(dock);
    Logger.DebugFormat("Recreated control {0}", (_control as Control).ID);
    return _control;
}
```

Generic Solution:

```
public interface ISetting<T>
{
    void SetSettings(T obj);
}

public void SetSettings(CormantRadDock dock)
{
    // do stuff with dock
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying the 2nd SetSettings is the override/implementation?  You say interface but you have an abstract class, and your SetSettings in ISetting is a generic method whereas the SetSettings body you show below is not.

Comment: I currently have the 2nd SetSettings implemented. I am trying to figure out how to either express the 2nd SetSettings so that it is able to override the abstract SetSettings, or... I'm not sure what other options there are.

Comment: Start by stating _what type_ you want to be generic... There are 2 candidates here, RadDockSetting and CormantRadDock . Which one should become `T` ? Or both, `T1` and `T2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
// move the generic type parameter up here so the interface is generic
// and not the method definition
public interface ISetting<T>
{
    void SetSettings(T obj);
}
```

Then you can implement it successfully in a class:

```
public class SomeClass: ISetting<YourSettingType>
{
    public void SetSettings(YourSettingType obj) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This was it. Sorry for my poor code up top. Friday's coffee hasn't kicked in yet.

Answer (score 0):

either

```
    public abstract class ISetting<T> 
{     
public abstract void SetSettings<T>(T obj); 
}  
public void SetSettings<T>(T dock) 
{     
// do stuff with dock 
}
```

or

```
    public abstract class ISetting<T> 
{     
public abstract void SetSettings(T obj); 
}  
public void SetSettings(T dock) 
{    
 // do stuff with dock 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public interface ICanBeRecreated<T>
{
    T Recreate();
}

public class CormantDock : ICanBeRecreated<CormantDock>
{
    private RadDockSetting _settings;

    private void ApplySettings(RadDockSetting settings)
    {
        // apply settings       
    }

    public CormantDock Recreate()
    {
        var dock = new CormantDock;
        dock.ApplySettings(_settings);
    }
}
```